# How to add a description to a Notion page via api?

Tags: notion-api, notion

I have a request with body like this:

```
{
    "parent": {
        "database_id": "<id>"
    },
    "properties": {
        "Name": {
            "title": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "content": "New note"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "Param 1": {
            "rich_text": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "content": "A dark green leafy vegetable"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "Param 2": {
            "rich_text": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "content": "A dark green leafy vegetable"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "Param 3": {
            "rich_text": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "content": "A dark green leafy vegetable"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How to add content of the page in this body?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jcUz.png)

Tried to add block "description" into body, but got responce with errors
Didnt find the information in api description

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://developers.notion.com/docs/working-with-page-content#creating-a-page-with-content), you may use a body like this:

```
{
   "parent": { "page_id": "..." },
   "properties": {
     "title": {
       "title": [{ "type": "text", "text": { "content": "A page title" } }]
     }
   },
   "children": [
     {
       "object": "block",
       "type": "paragraph",
       "paragraph": {
         "rich_text": [{ "type": "text", "text": { "content": "You made this page using the Notion API." } }]
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

for **a new page creation** by means of the endpoint `https://api.notion.com/v1/pages`.

On the other hand, having the existing page, you may [**append**](https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-block-children) child blocks with the body below:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "object": "block",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "paragraph": {
        "text": [{ "type": "text", "text": { "content": "– Notion API Team", "link": { "type": "url", "url": "https://twitter.com/NotionAPI" } } }]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```